# is my mysql query correct? (does not seem like it)

Tags: mysql, select, date

I want to select data between 1 week ago data until today data:

```
SELECT username, 
       email, 
       date 
FROM users 
WHERE date(date) BETWEEN (CURDATE() AND (CURDATE() - 7)) 
ORDER BY userid DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Hope you guys can help me. It does not work!!!

This question has been answered by **lexu**

(can somebody close this question?)

Comment: Have you got error in output or emty set?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1

Comment: if i change to: SELECT username, email, date FROM users WHERE date(date) = CURDATE(); No errors returned, but 0 result... why??? I have 100 over data in that tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT username
     , email
     , date 
FROM users 
WHERE date(date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 1 week) 
                     AND CURDATE() 
ORDER BY userid DESC
```

- [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) demands that you give the lower boundary first.
- use [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) with an interval of 1 week